# Ember.js: how to set associated model via select box

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My app has two models Url and UrlType and I want to select UrlType via select box. How do I do that? 
Here is the jsbin where I tried to reproduce the scenario, though this.get('store') do not work :( But the idea must be pretty clear.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nefas/6/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things with your jsbin.

- `this.store` din not work as you have not mentioned your adapter like this

  ```
   App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
  ```
- You din not return in the model `return`.

Though you have got around what you wanted, I have made a jsbin that might have what you want. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/saxuy/1/edit

#### Update

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/saxuy/6/edit

You could set the `url_type` attribute of your url model directly like this in your template.

```
{{view Ember.Select content=urlTypes optionLabelPath='content.caption' selection=url_type}}
```

If there was a `url_type` set for the model, it will be the selected option.

Comment: thank you! the problem is how to make select change the url_type_id attribute?

Comment: I have updated the jsbin like you wanted. For an `url` model, you could directly assign the `urlType` object not just id. Check the same jsbin, you would know.

Comment: Elegant approach! It's an discovery for me, thank you. 
Can you please look at the one more thing: I added a url_type_id:2 to the Url but this doesn't affect the select tag, though it must add 'selected' attribute to the appropriate url_type, isn't it http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cocop/1/edit ?

Comment: Awesome! The only thing left is to extract it in mixin. Cheers!

Comment: there is a bug here - sometimes, after selection the select box do not display names of the options. What do you think about that?

http://i.imgur.com/QvaWVd9.png

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your logic is working just fine

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nefas/12/edit

Comment: the problem is how to make select change the url_type_id attribute, so when user change url_type in the select field, the url model will change it's type accordingly.